# Running a JasperReport with JasperStarter doesn't create an output file

Tags: jasper-reports, hsqldb, jasperstarter

I have the following set-up:

- A LibreOffice Base `mybase.odb` connected to an HSQLDB Split-DB named `mydb`
- A form within with a button to open a report
- A macro behind this button that basically performs:

```cmd
   shell(convertToUrl(Tools.Strings.DirectoryNameOutOfPath( _
                      ThisComponent.Parent.getURL(), "/") & "myReport.cmd"), HIDE)
```

- `myReport.cmd` contains:

```cmd
    :: From: http://hsqldb.org/doc/2.0/guide/listeners-chapt.html#lsc_listener_types
    start /min java -cp %~dp0driver/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server
        --database.0 file:mydb --dbname.0 mydb

    timeout /t 3

    :: From: http://jasperstarter.cenote.de/index.html
    jasperstarter -v pr %~dp0myReport.jasper -r -o . -f pdf
        -H [localhost|127.0.0.1] --db-port 9001 -n mydb -u myuser
```

*[Line breaks inserted for easier reading here.]*

The HSQLDB server starts succesfully:

> ```
> ...
> [Server@1742700]: Startup sequence completed in 382 ms.
> [Server@1742700]: 2016-05-09 23:05:49.129 HSQLDB server 2.3.2 is online on port 9001
> ...
> ```

The subsequent `JasperStarter` doesn't show any error but no `PDF` is created.

Following the HSQLDB server output `Server@1742700` I also tried (with little hope):

```
jasperstarter ... -H 1742700 ... -n Server
```

to no avail.

The following in `myReport.cmd` works like a charm standalone:

```
jasperstarter pr %~dp0myReport.jasper -r -o . -f pdf -t generic
    --jdbc-dir %~dp0driver --db-driver org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver
    --db-url jdbc:hsqldb:file:%~dp0database/mydb;sql.syntax_mys=true;shutdown=true
    -u myuser
```

*[Line breaks inserted for easier reading here.]*

But not, of course, if `mybase.odb` is open:

> ```
> Unable to connect to database: Database lock acquisition failure: lockFile:
> org.hsqldb.persist.LockFile@68306856[file =<path>\database\mydb.lck, exists=true,
> locked=false, valid=false, ] method: checkHeartbeat read: 2016-05-09 21:25:13
> heartbeat - read: -6188 ms.
> ```

BTW, why `locked=false` when the lock file exists?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only one Java process at a time can connect to a file: database. The message indicates the second process cannot acquire a lock because the lock file has been created by the other process and does exist.

You should change the setup so that HSQLDB Server is started before you start LibreOffice. LibreOffice then connects to the server database, and your macro no longer starts the server and just starts the report generator with the Server URL.

Comment: Sounds reasonable. Thx. I'm going to try this.

Answer (score 2):

According to fredt's answer I created a `myapp.cmd` containing:

```cmd
start "My DB Server" /min java -cp %~dp0driver/hsqldb.jar org.hsqldb.server.Server
   --database.0 file:%~dp0database/mydb --dbname.0 mydb
timeout /t 2
start /b /max %~dp0mybase.odb
```

`myReport.cmd` now contains just:

```
jasperstarter -v pr %~dp0myReport.jasper -r -o %~dp0 -f pdf
   -H localhost --db-port 9001 -n mydb -u myuser
```

And I realized that:

```
jasperstarter ... -o .
```

doesn't work as expected. With '`.`' it took `C:\Program Files (x86)\LibreOffice 5\program` as output directory (comprehensible if invoked from within Base). Hence I changed it to the absolute `%~dp0`.